# Xfce: Tile window to left/right does not work for system windows

Tags: xfce, window-manager

In XFCE (4.14), tiling windows with custom shortcuts works as expected for application windows

[image: Tiling shortcuts]

These shortcuts do not work at all for system windows : Display, Keyboard, Window Manager.

Am I missing an hidden setting here ?

Comment: That is correct that this does not work for any of the system or settings windows, and why the developers have it that way I cannot tell you.  If you want it to work on those, I would suggest filing a bug against the tiling as a feature request to include all windows.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance , I logged an issue : https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/issues/537